# Derived Class Method Naming

Tags: c#, design, naming, object-oriented-design, naming-standards

I'm having a hard time coming up with a good naming convention for methods in derived classes that serve the same purpose as the methods in the base class. For example, if both the base class, and the derived class, need to initialize:

```
public class Foo()
{
    public void Initialize()
    {
        // base class initialization code here
        InitializeDerived();
    }

    // force derived classes to implement their own initialize method
    protected abstract void InitializeDerived();
}

public class Bar() : Foo
{
    protected override void InitializeDerived()
    {
        // initialization code here
    }
}
```

InitializeDerived() seems clunky. The only other option I can think of is to make the base class Initialize() method virtual. Then the derived class could override it, using the same name, and call the base class Initialize() method first.

Is there a better way? A better naming convention?

---

This may be a better example, because constructors won't solve the problem here. In this example, we have a rules engine where the client code polymorphically calls Process() on each rule:

```
public class RuleBase()
{
    public void Process()
    {
        // base class processing code here
        ProcessDerived();
    }

    // force derived classes to implement their own process method
    protected abstract void ProcessDerived();
}

public class RuleValidateHeight() : RuleBase
{
    protected override void ProcessDerived()
    {
        // derived class processing code here
    }
}
```

The consuming code:

```
foreach (Rule rule in rules)
{
    rule.Process()
}
```

Comment: This might sound terrible but you could use a number suffix like `Initialize2`.  That way you also have the option of marking the `Initialize2` sealed and then passing control down again to `Initialize3`

Answer (score 11):

In game programming I'm pretty used to the prefix 'On' so that you can think of the base class generating an 'event' when something is about to happen.

```
protected override void OnInitialize() { /*code here*/ }
protected override void OnProcess() { /*code here*/ }
```

This is called the [Template Method Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern), by the way.

As Martin comments below, other useful 'event' prefixes include Pre and Post. In a game context you'd typically have PreUpdate OnUpdate PostUpdate.

Comment: I like this. Also consider `PreProcess()` and `PostProcess()` to emphasis when the method will be called in case it's important to do the stuff after or before the parent `Process()`.

Comment: @MartinWickman Thank you for the pre- and post- tip. I like that.

Answer (score 4):

Use constructors for this instead.

```
public class Foo
{
    public Foo()
    {
        // initialization code here
    }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public Bar()
        : base() // base (Foo) constructor gets called first.
    {
        // initialization code for Bar goes here
    }
}
```

There are many reasons why, but the most compelling one is that newing up an object this way guarantees that you get back an object that is fully initialized on construction.

Comment: +1 for the tip. I may even be able to use your suggestion. The problem is that I'm dealing with some convoluted legacy code, and I may not be able to simply do what you suggest. We'll see. Thanks.

Comment: I just added a different scenario. Same problem, different slant. If you have any advice, it would be appreciated.

Comment: See my new answer.

Comment: I don't like this kind of answers which dictate the question owner to use a different tool/approach instead of suggesting a possible solution to the problem described. Clearly he's looking for an advice for naming a tool which is already provided by the language itself. The tool he's using is completely different than the suggested tool in this answer. Therefore, this answer is very polluting in my opinion.

Comment: @Xtro: Thanks for your opinion, but you might want to check the chronology of the posts here.  The OP didn't make it clear that constructors wouldn't work until 2 hours after I posted my answer, and leaving my answer here helps people reading the post to figure out what happened.  Also, note that the post you're commenting on is over four years old; it is, quite literally, ancient history.

Comment: My comment is not directly related to this question or to your answer. It was about a type of behavior which I observed on too many people on the internet for decades. It's still common; not history.

Comment: @Xtro: Apparently, focusing on irrelevancies is still a common behavior as well.

Comment: It's not as damaging as ignoring the actual need in the question at least.

Comment: @xtro: Let's try this again.  I posted an answer prior to the OP refining his question.  The OP thanked me for the answer, and even upvoted it.  There's nothing to see here.  You'd be better off focusing your efforts on something more interesting than this.

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is going to be easier if you can call Process from the derived class, and work your way up the inheritance tree instead of down:

```
public class Bar: Foo
{
    public override void Process()
    {
         base.Process();  // optional
         // Process Derived Rule here.
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 (again). I can't do this now, but I'll try this approach. I think this is exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: One thing I don't like about this approach is that if the call to `base.Process()` is not optional, developers must remember to add that line for each derived class.

Comment: @CongXu: It's not that hard to remember; you're *deliberately* overriding the base class's `Process()` method.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the difference between 'not that hard to remember' and 'impossible to forget' is a big one - IME code using this pattern in a team with many developers does result in the base not getting called where it should.

Comment: @CongXu has a good point. If the shared code is in the base class, and really must be called for things to work correctly, being optional isn't good. I think the template method design pattern is the way to go here, but then I'm back to my naming problem.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the method should say what the method does, instead of just saying where the method appears. Possible names would be:

```
ProcessRuleSpecifics
ProcessAfterInitialization
ResumeProcess
TerminateProcess
```

and so on

Comment: Why is this better than `ProcessDerived`?

Comment: It says what it does instead of just saying where it is declared.